# Cannot read property 'push' in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a component that will appear after a second.
The component itself simply has only H1.
I use a router so the most correct solution would seem to me to use the history.push but it does not work for me, what am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Hello from './comp/Hello';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
      </div>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
  componentWillMount() {
  this.hello()
  }
  hello(){
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.props.history.push('/hello')
    }, 1000);
  }
}
export default App;



===========================the Component========================




import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (    
      <div className="App">
      <h1>hi</h1>
      </div>    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: We can't help you without seeing how you're using `App`, since it looks like there's no `history` prop given to it. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: The App component is outside the router, you cannot use `this.props.history` there

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to wrap you component with withRouter hook .
try like below,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Hello from './comp/Hello';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
      </div>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
  componentWillMount() {
  this.hello()
  }
  hello(){
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.props.history.push('/hello')
    }, 1000);
  }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: I also thought but then just crashed again with the error:   Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see exactly what is going on, usually only child components suffer from these kinds of errors in my experience, because the props.history is not being passed on. The Apps component should in most cases be the main component though.

Regardless, in the meantime I suggest you try this approach:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
...
hello(){
    setTimeout(() => {
     return <Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/hello",
        state: {
          optionalStateToPass,
        },
      }} />;
    }, 1000);
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For a component to receive the `history` prop, you need 2 things:

1. `Router` must be at the top level, above all calls to `Route`, `Link`, and `withRouter`
2. The component that needs the prop `history` must be rendered by a `Route`, e.g. `<Route component={ComponentThatNeedsHistoryProp} ...>` *OR* wrap it with `withRouter`.

In your case, it seems you cannot rely on the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) to be passed, so we need to use `withRouter`.
It should look like this (imports not shown):

```
// App.js
class App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Hello />
    </Router>
  </div>
)
```

```
// Hello.js
class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>hi</h1>
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.hello()
  }

  hello(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/hello')
    }, 1000);
  }
}
export default withRouter(Hello);
```

Comment: Thank man! but now in Hello.js there is no h1 anymore (sorry if it's a noob question but i am new to all this)

Comment: Well you can make `Hello` render anything you want, like your h1. Edited the answer to include the h1